# Python: Open and read remote text files on Windows

Tags: python, windows, text-files, remote-access, readfile

Im trying to find a module that will allow me to run a script locally that will:
1. Open a text file on a remote Windows Machine
2. Read the lines of the text file
3. Store the lines in a variable and be able to process the data.
This is absolutely no problem on a Linux machine via SSH, but I have no clue what module to use for a remote Windows machine. I can connect no problem and run commands on a remote Windows machine via `WMI`,but `WMI` does not have a way to read/write to files. Are there any modules out there that I can install to achieve this process?

Comment: Welcome to SO. If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can use powershell for this.

first Open powershell by admin previlage.

Enter this command

> Enable-PSRemoting -Force

Enter this command also on both computer so they trust eachother.

> Set-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts *

then restart winrm service on both pc by this command.

> Restart-Service WinRM

test it by this command

> Test-WsMan computername

for executing a Remote Command.

> Invoke-Command -ComputerName COMPUTER -ScriptBlock { COMMAND }
>   -credential USERNAME

for starting remote session.

> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName COMPUTER -Credential USER